# Does any program automatically measure typing speed?

Tags: keyboard-listener

I like programs like [IOGraphica](http://iographica.com/) and [Mouseotron](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/mousotron.html), which can track mouse movement over time autonomously and give you running stats at any time.

I want something like this for typing. Does such a thing exist? A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=automatic+typing+speed+program) just gives me one-shot typing tests, but I want to measure my day-to-day speed.

Comment: For what OS? What is your price limit?

Comment: @Izzy Same as IOGraphica and Mouseotron

Comment: And what same are those? Please don't expect us to read a bunch of external sites to find out what you want. Most people then will just skip your question. Take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Being around here for more than 2 years, you should know that ;)